# Headphone is not working

Tags: 10.10, sound

I am running ubuntu 10.10 on a Lenovo ideapad z560. The speakers run fine but the headphones are not recognized when i plug them in. Audio comes out of the speakers only. I tried all alsa and pulseaudio settings but to no avail. I came to know that this is a known bug and many people are having this problem. I was wondering whether shifting to OSS4 would help. I need some advice because once i make the switch i would need to reconfigure a large number of audio apps. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to explicitly set the sound card's model in the `alsa-base.conf` file?

- [Re: headphone jack not recognised by ubuntu 10.10](http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10050353&postcount=16)
- [HdaIntelSoundHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto)

Comment: Iam trying out the linuxant drivers. hope this works.

Comment: The hdaintelsoundhowto solved my problem. Thanks a lot for the fix.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise that you leave your sound servers alone, maybe you should try if a USB based headphone will help work around the problem until the bug is fixed, also make sure that it is really not a hardware issue, I had an old Dell Inspiron that had a similar problem and it turned out that the problem was hardware failure, Windows that came on it with the proper drivers had the same problem.