# Speakers continue to play even after I plug in headphones on a Satellite L640

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are my speakers working but not my headphones?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31317/why-are-my-speakers-working-but-not-my-headphones)

Im using ubuntu 11.04 and window 7 in toshiba satellite L640. Normal jack headphone is working in windows 7 but it is not working in ubuntu 11.04. sound keeps coming out onboard speakers while plug in headphone.

- Analogue Headphones Option is not at "Sound Settings" the "Output" tab

Comment: What kind of Headphone is it? USB or Normal jack.

Comment: If USB then paste the lsusb output. And try to execute dmesg by unpluing and plugin your head-phone.

Comment: Please be descriptive. What isn't working? Is it that sound keeps coming out of the onboard speakers when you plug in your headphones? Help us help you.

Comment: (Normal jack headphone) sound keeps coming out onboard speakers while plug in headphone.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/12444/43103       I got answer by this link. thanks askubuntu. I like ubuntu....

Answer (score 0):

Open the dash and type "Sound Settings" then open it. Go to the "Output" tab and switch the connector drop-down-box to "Analogue Headphones" and then try them again.

Also 11.04 is not the latest release of Ubuntu, you might want to consider installing 11.10.

Comment: Analogue Headphones Option is not at "Sound Settings" the "Output" tab