# sound for headphones no longer works but does work on windows

Tags: 14.04, sound, headphones

Since a few days ago the sound of my headphones no longer works. I have tried the headphones over via Windows and then they do work (same computer, dual boot). I have already tried the following:

- [Headphone is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12430/headphone-is-not-working)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/457708/headphones-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04
- [restore speakers / headphones option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128099/restore-speakers-headphones-option)

but none of these methods worked for me. The sound does work from the normal built-in speakers.

Anybody know a fix?

Here is the output for

`wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh`

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=028ff6475c1ce6661119cb4f3a0dd6cc60af86ba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this points:

1. **Windows problem**: Some users have reported that you must really "shutdown" pc from Windows8 , just "reboot" cause audio problems. Also, "fastboot" must be disabled in the bios.
2. **Pulseaudio problem**: in the "sound parameters"  output tab, you should see device  automatically changing from speaker to headphone when you plug a jack . As Pulseaudio stores independent level for each state, it could be bad just for headphone .
   You can also run this command a terminal to reset pulseaudio config:
   `rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k`
3. **Alsa setting problem**: Do you see "headphones" fader  when you launch  `alsamixer` in a terminal (eventually press F6 function key to select your main soundcard which is the "not hdmi" one).
   The fader must be unmuted (check toggle mute by pressing "m" key when the headphone fader is selected via left/right arrow keys). Set fader level with up/down keys.

**Finally, a software update solved the problem**

If nothing works, run "Alsa-info" to show your audio config (someone can have an idea) :  copy the following command in a terminal , choose "upload" option  when asked ("tab" key to select it) an post url printed at the end.
`wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh`

Comment: I don't use windows 8 but windows 7 so it cannot be 1. I have tried 2 and 3 but neither worked. Can you see what it is from the alsa project page?

Comment: Run the alsa-info, post the result url,  it will give soundcard  codec name and possible tweak in  alsa-base.conf (by adding options snd-hda-intel model=xxxx   )

Comment: I have posted the info in the OP

Comment: From alsainfo, Master and pcm faders are now muted : use alsamixer :you will see "mm"  under the  2 faders: scroll to the faders ,press "m" to unmute them so that "mm" is "00"

Comment: Also test changing "automute" in alsamixer to have "speaker " and not "speaker line out", test also "off"

Comment: IF no success, try to tweak alsa-base.conf : run `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` , add this line at the end : `options snd-hda-intel model=ref`   then reboot

Comment: I ran a software update and it has suddenly started working again, don't know why but I will accept this answer

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to fix this issue as well for easily half an hour now, and your second point fixed it _instantly_.